# C# Reading in strings from a Text File

Tags: c#, wpf

This is probably a simple one for you guys… I have a ViewModel Class that generates a collection of strings which I later bind to my UI. I would like to change the logic so that instead of entering the strings manually, it reads them in from a .txt file (therefore I give it a path to a file and it reads in the words from that file). Can anyone provide a quick solution? Many thanks - Ben

```
public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        Words = LoadWords();

    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Words { get; private set; }

    private static IEnumerable<string> LoadWords()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        string loremIpsum =
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
        string[] tokens = loremIpsum.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            words.Add(tokens[random.Next(tokens.Count())]);
        }
        return words;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear do you want to read the data from text file or what

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [File.ReadAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)

```
private static IEnumerable<string> LoadWords(String filePath)
{
      List<String> words = new List<String>();
      foreach(String line in ReadAllLines(filePath))
      {

        string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            words.Add(tokens[random.Next(tokens.Count())]);
        }
      }
      return words;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I want to read in my words from a file stored at a specific location. So I want to give it a file path and then it reads the words stored in that text file. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @Ben. The ReadAllLines method takes a 'filePath' string. Simply move that into the parameter list for the method...

Comment: Sorry i'm being a bit slow: So I have - private static IEnumerable<string> LoadWords(String "some filePath") is this what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer to just put the parameter in which I'd missed out before.

Comment: Thanks, can't seem to get this working, so I have replaced filepath with the actual path i.e @"c:\my documents\words.txt"

Comment: Also lastly I keep seeing the error ReadAllLines does not exist in current context. I am using System.IO namespace am I missing anything else?

Comment: Ignore that I was missing the File keyword. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Define your `Words` as `ObservableCollection<String>` and not `Enumerable<string>`. As far as I can see, this should be enough to bind it to UI: Rest of your code seems fine to me.

if you need to get the context of a file, use `File.ReadAllText()`.

### UPDATE

Use this snippet which does a better job in tokenising:

```
string filename = @"c:\myfile.txt";
string content = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        ObservableCollection<string> strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(content,@"\b(\S+)\b"))
{
    strings.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I want to read in my words from a file stored at a specific location. So I want to give it a file path and then it reads the words stored in that text file. Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string line = "";
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("PathToFile"))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Trim() != "")
        {
         string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
         //Process the tokens
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will read a text file into your string array (assumes each string is on a new line):

```
    TextReader tr = File.OpenText("c:\LoremIpsum.txt");
    string s = null;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    while ((s = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        list.Add(s);
    }
    string[] tokens = list.ToArray();
```